# I can't pull the links on the map in the website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

**All the href data on the website are coming, but the links on the map are not**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome (executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.oyuncakhouse.com/")
# identify elements with tagname <a>
lnks = driver.page_source
lnks=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@href]')
# traverse list
for lnk in lnks:
   # get_attribute() to get all href
   print(lnk.get_attribute("href"))
driver.quit()
```

**map on site picture:**

[image]

**Tags:**

[image]

Comment: The anchor tags are shown in a frame. They are not in the source you are looking for.

Comment: I added it as a picture.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with the x-path `//a[@href]`  instead of `//*[@href]` as given below.

```
lnks=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//a[@href]')
```

Comment: I tried this process, but the links in the map did not come. Nothing has changed unfortunately :/